# Como alinhar paragrafos ao lado da imagem em HTML e CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estou com um teste em `.html` e `.css` e queria alinhar o texto do lado da imagem, como posso fazer isso? Queria coloca-lo onde a seta mostra.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
        <title> </title>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilof.css"/>

  </head>
        <body>
                <div id="wrap">
                    <header>
                        <h1 align="center">Fsociety Page</h1>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="link-img.html" alt="fsociety">Inicio</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="formularios.html">Formulário</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Sobre</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <h2 align="center">Mr Robot Fans</h2>   
                    <p> Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste </p>
                    <p> Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste 
                    </p>
                <figure id="img">
                    <img src="img/fsociety.png" alt="fsociety"/>
                    <figcaption><strong>Fsociedade</strong></figcaption>
                </figure>                   
        </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta dar float: left na imagem

```
<figure id="img" style="float: left">
    <img src="img/fsociety.png" alt="fsociety"/>
    <figcaption><strong>Fsociedade</strong></figcaption>
</figure>  

<h2 align="center">Mr Robot Fans</h2>   
<p> Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste </p>
<p> Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste 
</p>
```

Comment: Ja foi dado o float left no código css...

Comment: mas a ordem estava errada, veja que eu coloquei o html da imagem **antes** do html do texto.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um nova div e coloca a imagem e o texto. Formate a div

```
.div
{
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100px;/* Aqui você pode alterar */
  display: flex;
}
.txt{
  /* A classe do texto */
  float: right;
}
```